# How to enable Backface culling in all preview modes

Tags: rendering

I am pretty new to Blender (I'm a Max guy) and I want to have backface cull on whether I'm in render preview or material preview. I have it enabled in solid preview mode but can't seem to enable it in other viewing modes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Blender use both side of the faces at rendering, thats why you see the back faces in the material and render preview. If you really want to hide the backfaces in the other views, you can make a shader which is transparent only from the backface with the Geometry shader node. Of course in this case the backfaceculling will be visible on the render. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/geometry.html